# Find the coordinates of G, given that FG is the diameter of circle, and F=(9,5) while X, the center of the circle = (5,-3).

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I had the answer: Coordinates of G= (1,-11), but the answer key states that the answer is: coordinates of G= (1,-17). I'm not sure as to whether there is a typo in the answer key, or that my answer is incorrect. Any help would be useful. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $\overrightarrow{FG}=2\overrightarrow{FX}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center point between $G(1,-11)$ and $F(9,5)$ (mean of $(x,y)$ coordinates) is $ X(5,-3)$, and so you are right.

Comment: ok thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. What do you want to believe?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I did draw the diagram and ended up with one that is similar to yours.

Comment: You're most welcome